# how to check if a jar has advice woven into it

Tags: aspectj

We have a jar file where we are expecting transaction advice woven into them. But, when we deploy this jar and during runtime, we keep getting the "Unable to locate current JTA transaction". indicating that the advice is not correctly available.

I couldn't find any articles or blogs or material which talked about verifying/checking if aspects are actually woven into a jar file.

If there is already any page which talks about this, please point me to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `javap` tool you can verify if a class has been woven by AspectJ. For just a quick check whether the class is woven anywhere, check if the class has a WeaverVersion attribute:

```
javap -private -verbose com.foo.SomeClass

...
org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverVersion: length = 0xC
 00 07 00 00 00 00 01 4F B3 FA 4E D0 
...
```

To verify whether individual locations in the class file have been woven, repeat the javap command but look for the methods you expect to be woven in the output - do those methods call out to `ajc$` name prefixed methods? Those will represent calls to AspectJ advice.

The simplest way to tell though may be to use `-showWeaveInfo` when compiling the system in the first place and producing the woven jar, do the weave info messages that come out indicate the locations you expect to be woven?

Answer (score 1):

Another option will be to extract an entity `.class` file from the `.jar`/`.war` that is expected to be woven and open it with IntelliJ. The IDE uses a Java bytecode decompiler that shows the class file as a readable `.java` file.

Next, to check if it has been woven, just look at the implemented interfaces. You'll have something like the following:

```
public class MyEntity implements Cloneable, PersistenceWeaved, PersistenceEntity, PersistenceObject, FetchGroupTracker, PersistenceWeavedFetchGroups, PersistenceWeavedLazy, ChangeTracker, PersistenceWeavedChangeTracking, PersistenceWeavedRest {
    ...
}
```